# Why would snmp.exe utilize 1.2GB of memory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, snmp

We particularly don't use snmp for anything significant, at least not that I'm aware of. Is it normal for snmp.exe to consume 1.2GB after 285 hours of up time? Seems a bit excessive. Why would snmp.exe consume so much memory? Is there a way to configure snmp.exe so it doesn't?

Comment: Are you actually using it? If not, disable it.

Comment: would remote desktop services enable snmp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SNMP doesn't run by default on Server 2008 R2. It is an optional feature that can be installed and uninstalled, and even when installed, it runs as a Windows service that can be started, stopped, and disabled.

The Microsoft SNMP engine is not very flexible in its configuration options. Microsoft plans to deprecate their implementation of SNMP altogether, hence why they never made an SNMPv3 engine.

It should never be using 1.2GB of memory. I would say something is wrong, such as a memory leak.

If you don't use it, turn it off.